# is there efficient way for pandas to get tail rows with a condition

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, tail

I want to get tail rows with a condition

For example:
I want to get all negative tail rows from a column 'A' like:

```
    test = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-8, -9, -10, 1, 2, 3, 0, -1,-2,-3]})
```

I expect a 'method' to get new frame like:

```
        A
    0  -1
    1  -2
    2  -3
```

note that, it is not certain of how many 'negative' numbers are in the tail. So I can not run test.tail(3)

It looks like the pandas provided 'tail()' function can only run with a given number.

But my input data frame might be too large that I dont want run a simple loop to check one by one

Is there a smart way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the tail for? It seems like you just need the negative numbers

```
test.query("A < 0")
```

Update: Find where sign changes, split the array and choose last one

```
split_points = (test.A.shift(1)<0) == (test.A<0) 
np.split(test, split_points.loc[lambda x: x==False].index.tolist())[-1]
```

Output:

```
    A
7   -1
8   -2
9   -3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I only want the tail rows, I just updated the example in my description, please check:)

Comment: this looks an elegant one, I have concern about performance since it applies to all of the data frame

Comment: You can test it with %%timeit and let us know :) @Marco_CH solution is correct too, and probably faster

Comment: I tested and compared @Macro_CH and your code, yes Macro_CH's answer performs better

Comment: Patryk, please refer my updated test result!

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you wanted?

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-8, -9, -10, 1, 2, 3, 0, -1,-2,-3]})

test = test.iloc[::-1]

test.loc[test.index.max():test[test['A'].ge(0)].index[0]+1]
```

**Output:**

```
    A
9   -3
8   -2
7   -1
```

---

**edit**, if you want to get it back into the original order:

```
test.loc[test.index.max():test[test['A'].ge(0)].index[0]+1].iloc[::-1]

    A
7   -1
8   -2
9   -3
```

Optional also `.reset_index(drop=True)` if you need a index starting at 0.

Comment: no, you can't assume you know the first negative number is -1

Comment: It doesn't assume the first number to be `-1`. This `-1` is for reversing the dataset. It works with each combinations at the end, also if there aren't negative numbers (then it will return an empty result).

Comment: I tested, it is correct and performs good!

Comment: HI @Marco_CH, after my second round test, to my suprize, actually many of the times, Patryk's code can perform slightly better, or at least both methods are very similar. As Patryk's code is easier to read, so I end up with that one. I can only select one solution, so hand write thanks to you!

Answer (score 2):

Just share a picture of performance comparing above two given answers
Thansk Patry and Macro
[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing this comparison. Nevertheless, great solution Patryk, thanks for sharing this approach!

Answer (score 2):

I improved my above test, and did another round test, as I feel the old 'testing sample' size was too small,and afaid the `%%time` measurement might not accurate.

My new test uses a very big head numbers with size of 10000000 and tail with 3 negative numbers

so the new test can prove how the whole data frame size impact the over all performance.

code is like bellow:

```
    %%time
    arr = np.arange(1,10000000,1)
    arr = np.concatenate((arr, [-2,-3,-4]))
    test = pd.DataFrame({'A':arr})
    test = test.iloc[::-1]
    test.loc[test.index.max():test[test['A'].ge(0)].index[0]+1].iloc[::-1]
```

```
    %%time
    arr = np.arange(1,10000000,1)
    arr = np.concatenate((arr, [-2,-3,-4]))
    test = pd.DataFrame({'A':arr})
    split_points = (test.A.shift(1)<0) == (test.A<0) 
    np.split(test, split_points.loc[lambda x: x==False].index.tolist())[-1]
```

due to system impacts, I tested 10 times, the above 2 methods are very much performs the similar. In about 50% cases Patryk's code even performs faster

Check out this image bellow

[image]

Comment: Thanks for double checking! Using %%timeit instead of %%time might be better - it eliminates system processes from the equation. Anyway - in this case, as you said, the solutions are very similar. If you want to cut some more time, instead of using np.split with split_points you can just use the last split point to index manually: like `test[split_points[-1]:]` or similar

Comment: oh,yes, that's a good idea